# Cordova plugin cordova-sqlite-storage is not working in IOS , window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase() function is not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, sqlite, phonegap-plugins, cordova-ios

can someone please help me with this cordova sqlite database ? its working fine in android , but in ios i am not able to run this below code.. i have tried both **window.openDatabase** and **window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase ( included cordova plugin cordova-sqlite-storage)** ,

I am getting the **alert('start')** in device but not the **alert('dbalert END')** .... and the app gets stuck here can anyone help with this ...... this isssue **occurs only in IOS**

inside my app.js  i have called DB.init() in deviceready event inside my app.

I am using IONIC framework with cordova 4.x > IOS , This issue occurs only in IOS , works perfectly in android

```
 angular.module('Busslip').factory('DB', function($q, DB_CONFIG) 
 {
    var self = this;
    self.db = null;

    self.init = function() {
         //Use  in production
         alert('start');
        self.db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: DB_CONFIG.name});
        alert('dbalert END');
        alert(DB_CONFIG.name); //// here i get DB in alert 
        //self.db  = window.openDatabase(DB_CONFIG.name);
        //self.db = window.openDatabase(DB_CONFIG.name, '1.0', 'database', -1);
        //self.db = window.sqlitePlugin.o  penDatabase(DB_CONFIG.name, '2');
      alert('dbalert END');
        angular.forEach(DB_CONFIG.tables, function(table) {
            var columns = [];

            angular.forEach(table.columns, function(column) {
                columns.push(column.name + ' ' + column.type);
            });

            var query = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + table.name + ' (' + columns.join(',') + ')';
            self.query(query);
            console.log('Table ' + table.name + ' initialized');
        });
    };

    self.query = function(query, bindings) {
        bindings = typeof bindings !== 'undefined' ? bindings : [];
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        self.db.transaction(function(transaction) {
            transaction.executeSql(query, bindings, function(transaction, result) {
                deferred.resolve(result);
            }, function(transaction, error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    self.fetchAll = function(result) {
        var output = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
            output.push(result.rows.item(i));
        }

        return output;
    };

    self.fetch = function(result) {
        return result.rows.item(0);
    };

    return self;
})
```